# Что означает эта ошибка?Runtime Library

Tags: c++

Пишу программу для подсчёта символов с бинарного файла
Количество символов считает,выводит но после подсчёта вместо завершения программы выскакивает такое исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно не указывает на мой код,оно указывает на файл istype.c
Я зашёл и глянул строку 68

```
_ASSERTE(c >= -1 && c <= 255);
```

Я так полагаю что я упустил какую-то кодировку,потому что если бы на мой код ругалось бы,то всё бы указывало на него.

Отладчик показывает все нужные значения правильно.

Часть кода(здесь выводится количество повторяющихся символов)

```
void calculate_symb(FILE* fd)
{
    int max = 0;
    fd = fopen("test.dat", "rb");

    if (!fd)
        printf("Ошибка!Файл не найден!\n");
    else
    {
        fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END);
        long fsize = ftell(fd);
        int n = fsize;
        cout << "Количество символов в файле = " << fsize << endl;
        char* symv = new char[n];
        fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        cout << "Вывод содержимого двоичного файла:" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fread(symv, sizeof(char), n, fd);
            cout << symv[i];
        }

        fclose(fd);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Повторяющиеся символы" << endl;

        for (int x = 0; x < 255; x++)
        {
            bool flag = true;

            if (isalnum(symv[x]))
                for (int y = x - 1; y >= 0 && flag; y--)
                    if (symv[x] == symv[y])
                        flag = false;

            if (flag && isalnum(symv[x]))
                cout << "\"" << symv[x] << "\"" << " ->  " << count(symv, symv + 255,
                        symv[x]) << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно увидеть код?

Comment: Если не секрет, а зачем передавать `FILE*fd` как параметр?... И кто будет освобождать память под `symv`? И - вас не смущает, что программа дает неверные результаты (где два `r` в вашем слове?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не будем касаться самого алгоритма - он, как видим, не работает. А не работает, в частности, и потому, что у вас есть как минимум обращение за границами массива - при `x >= n`. И одно это уже теоретически ведет к undefined behaviour.

Смысл же ошибки в том, что какой-то из функций `is...` - видимо, `isalnum` - передано значение, выходящее за рамки `char` и `EOF` - вы же в курсе, что аргументом этих функций является `int`?

Где именно и как именно это происходит - имеет смысл смотреть при наличии минимального воспроизводимого кода.

Пока разберитесь с алгоритмом. Как вариант - вот такой, попроще :) Не лучший вариант, но просто чтоб поменьше править ваш код, оставил и жестко прошитый файл, и чтение через `fread`, вобщем, вам есть где развернуться :) Те же проверки на "буквоциферность" (как минимум для красоты вывода, если будут какие-то переводы строк, например) вставьте самостоятельно.

```
void calculate_symb()
{
    FILE * fd = fopen("test.dat","rb");
    if (!fd)
        printf("Ошибка!Файл не найден!\n");
    else
    {
        int symv[256] = { 0 };
        int fsize = 0;
        cout<<"Вывод содержимого двоичного файла:"<<endl;
        char symbol;
        while(fread(&symbol, sizeof(char), 1, fd))
        {
            fsize++;
            cout << symbol;
            symv[symbol]++;
        }
        fclose(fd);
        cout<<"Количество символов в файле = "<<fsize<<endl;

        cout<<"Повторяющиеся символы"<<endl;
        for(int x = 0; x<=255; x++)
        {
            if (symv[x]) cout << "\"" << (char)x << "\" -> " << symv[x] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена была таким образом

1)Для начала добавил нуль-терминатор '\0'для своей строки.

2)Плюс пошаговый отладчик в переменной l к строке прибавлял символ-крякозябру,отсюда он и ругался на исключение,так как не понимал что за символ и не мог его просто найти среди 255 наименований.

3)Да он неправильно считал количество букв и эта проблема тоже была решена путём добавления в цикл переменной l,которая считывает количество символов со строки с помощью strlen.

Исправленный фрагменты кода(до цикла)

```
char* symv = new char[n];
    symv[n+1]='\0';
    fseek(fd,0L,SEEK_SET);
    cout<<"Вывод содержимого двоичного файла:"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fread(symv, sizeof(char), n, fd);
        cout << symv[i]; 
    }
    fclose(fd);
    cout<<endl;
    int l=strlen(symv);

    cout<<"Повторяющиеся символы:"<<endl;
    for(int x = 0; x<l-1; x++)
```

В итоге всё работает без исключений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]